# How to rename a pandas DataFrame index label based on other column value

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a df and I am trying to update the value of some labels in the multiIndex based on the value of the columns on the same row.

At the moment, I drop the index level and use some masking as if it was a value column, but I feel there must be a much cleaner way of doing this

```py
iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['A', 'B']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['loadcase', 'location'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), index=index, columns=['fx','fy','fz'])
df

                        fx       fy       fz
loadcase location                           
bar      A        -3.8e-01  2.3e-01 -2.3e+00
         B        -1.4e+00 -7.4e-01  2.6e-01
baz      A         1.1e+00 -1.1e+00 -1.2e-01
         B         5.6e-01  3.7e-01  2.8e+00
foo      A         6.2e-02 -6.2e-02 -9.7e-01
         B        -5.7e-01 -6.4e-01 -1.1e+00
qux      A         2.5e+00 -1.0e-01  4.1e-02
         B        -9.2e-01  9.8e-02 -1.0e+00

# drop the index location so it can be easily searched for.    
df.reset_index(level="location", inplace=True)

mask = (df["location"] == 'A') & (df["fx"] < 0)
df["location"].loc[mask] = "{}_NEG".format('A')

mask2 = df["location"] == 'A'
df["location"].loc[mask2] = "{}_POS".format('A')

#returning the index like it is the standard
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index(["loadcase","location"], inplace=True)
```

This gives me the expected result:

```py
                        fx       fy       fz
loadcase location                           
bar      A_NEG    -3.8e-01  2.3e-01 -2.3e+00
         B        -1.4e+00 -7.4e-01  2.6e-01
baz      A_POS     1.1e+00 -1.1e+00 -1.2e-01
         B         5.6e-01  3.7e-01  2.8e+00
foo      A_POS     6.2e-02 -6.2e-02 -9.7e-01
         B        -5.7e-01 -6.4e-01 -1.1e+00
qux      A_POS     2.5e+00 -1.0e-01  4.1e-02
         B        -9.2e-01  9.8e-02 -1.0e+00
```

But it is quite ugly and I would prefer not to drop the index to a regular column. How can you mask a dataframe and at the same time access the label (or a specific column) to change the values?

Additionally, I get the error SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame, which after looking at the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) still cannot make sense out of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Your data frame has two columns named `fx`. This could be very dangerous when you use values `fx` to change things.

Comment: updated the typo, shoud have been fz

Comment: Indices are immutable

Answer (score 0):

I finally got around it with DataFrame.rename() function